# Unable to clone odoo 9 in linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Gnome version

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, github, odoo-9

Unable to clone odoo 9; got below error twice ...

```
demo@trial:~/project/odoo/odoo_9$ git clone https://www.github.com/odoo/odoo --depth 1 --branch 9.0 --single-branch
Cloning into 'odoo'...
remote: Counting objects: 23395, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (20065/20065), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
demo@trial:~/project/odoo/odoo_9$
```

Any Idea ... ??

I am using linux ->  Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - Gnome version